# If a finite group $G$ is generated by two elements $x$ and $y$, then do $x$ and $xy$ also generate it?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In my problem, I am asked to show the alternating group $A_4$ can be generated by two elements $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2=y^3=(xy)^3=1$, where $1$ is the identity. By a proposition in my text, I know $A_4$ is generated by $(123)$ and $(124)$, but of course, these two don't meet the given requirements. I do know, via some brute force, that $(13)(24)$ meets the requirement of $x$, leaving $(123)$ to be $y$, since $A_4 = <(123),(13)(24)>$. And since $(123)(124)=(13)(24)$, I know in this case that my question holds.
However, this is a homework problem, and while 12 calculations is not so much to write out, I later have to show a similar statement regarding $A_5$, but 60 calculations is a bit tedious, to both compute and write, and there are the groups in addition as well.
Any help/hints would be appreciated

Comment: Sure. If $G$ is a finite group, then $x$ has some finite order; call it $n$. Then $x^{n-1} \in \langle x, xy\rangle$, and so $x^{n-1}xy = x^{n}y = y \in \langle x, xy\rangle$.

Comment: Ah yes, I was thinking that might work. Then to get $y^2$ for example, we could just take $(yx)(x^{n-2})(xy) = yey = y^2$, and then continue in a similar fashion for $y^{m-1}$ where $m$ is the order of $y$, correct?

Comment: @AWertheim Actually, the finiteness hypothesis is not needed as in the context of groups $\langle x,xy\rangle$ denotes the smallest *group* containing $x$ and $xy$, hence automatically contains $x^{-1}$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, ah, indeed, that's much better. I guess I got sloppy when posting the first thing that came to mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint.* Can you make $y$ out of $x$ and $xy$?

Comment: Thank you for the hint, the other comment answered it for me. I understand it is indeed true applying the (easy) "trick" multiple times to obtain any elements in the group.